# MYSQL query syntax - subquery with trim

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, trim

I have 2 tables

Table1 -> msqt_subjects

```
  id  category 
 - 1   maths
 - 2   physics
 - 3   history
```

Table2 -> msqt_class

```
  id  subjects
 - 1   ,1,2,3,
```

My query is

> select `id`, `category` from `msqt_subjects` where `id` IN (select TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM `subjects`) from `msqt_class` where `id` =1)

It returns only one row, actually it has to return 3 rows.

When I run subquery seperately it result as `1,2,3`.

I like to use as single query instead of seperate queries.

Is the query correct?

Comment: Thats a bad DB designed and you should normalize the table first.

Comment: @Abhik do you want to add ids as individual record in class table?

Comment: Yes you should `find_in_set` etc are just work around. When you have large data set you will feel the necessity of normalization so its better to do it from beginning. create a table `class` with classid and name, then create another table called `class_subject(id pk, classid, subjectid )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ms.id, ms.category 
FROM msqt_subjects ms 
INNER JOIN msqt_class mc ON mc.subjects LIKE CONCAT('%,', ms.id, ',%')
WHERE mc.id = 1;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT ms.id, ms.category 
FROM msqt_subjects ms 
INNER JOIN msqt_class mc ON FIND_IN_SET(ms.id, TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM mc.subjects))
WHERE mc.id = 1;
```